# I tried to post a comment to an answer, but I got Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes. How do I get around this?

Tags: discussion, comments

Sorry, Stack Exchange, but some people type slow and might need more than 5 minutes to type out a comment. How can I post a comment to an answer to my question, for clarification, if the site's policy won't let me do so?!

Answer (score 4):

You can take as much time as you need to write your comment. However, once you've saved it, you only have a 5-minute window by which you can edit it. This allows you to fix a typo you've spotted right after you've saved it, but doesn't allow for changing the content of a comment later on, when there may have been a response.

Traffic is pretty light here, so your best bet is probably just to delete the old comment and try again with a new one.